# Hypothesis testing for proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

In a contact center, the agents reach out to advertisers to offer digital marketing solutions. There are two ways to reach the customer - 1 is cold calling and the second is a scheduled call (resulting from a cold call). I want to test the hypothesis if one of the channels is better than the other in terms of conversion rate. I have daily conversion rate percentage for the last 3 months. which test should I apply? I think z-test for 2 proportions...but do I apply it on the aggregate for the last 3 months or on monthly conversion rate?

Comment: If you have daily data then you should use this, don't aggregate it.

Comment: You could benefit from using a [tag:control-chart]

Comment: Thanks.   I have performed z-test for 2 proportions on 30 samples of varied sample size, all > 30. Interestingly, the claim is supported in half of the samples and rejected in the other half. What else can I do to draw an inference?